# Highchart doesnt load when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, csv, highcharts

My second highchart doesnt seem to load. I cant figure out what I did wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/2k9k9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#b").click(function () {

    $.get('dataset/verkeer.csv', function (data) {
var series = preprocessData(data);
var i = chart.series.length;
while (i--) {
    chart.series[0].remove(false); //remove all prevbious series
} 
console.log('hoi');
   i = series.length;
while(i--){
     chart.addSeries(series[i], true);   
}

});
});
});
```

I used the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vDac6/

Comment: I don't think you can load 'dataset/verkeer.csv' in jsfiddle ? Try updating the fiddle to use a locally defined version of the csv data.

Comment: Thats whats done in the example fiddle. If I change the hard coded data to csv my code somehow stops working.. whoops this is the link to my ex. http://jsfiddle.net/pEU89/

Comment: jsfiddle doens't allow to load csv from extrenal sources, so please run it in your webserver and let us know how your csv looks like and if you receive any errors in console